# SPLoaderError.loadComponentError: Failed to load component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sharepoint-online, spfx

Developed a SharePoint app in SPFX Framework, when I compile it with gulp build it compiles fine, however when I do gulp serve and I add the app to the workbench and get this following error:

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:***Failed to load component "6d68696e-6767-4686-9cd4-60788de11f47" (DocumentUploadWebPart). 
>   Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "6d68696e-6767-4686-9cd4-60788de11f47" (DocumentUploadWebPart).
>   Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/6d68696e-6767-4686-9cd4-60788de11f47_0.0.1 external__react_.createClass is not a function
>   ***INNERERROR:***Failed to load entry point from component "6d68696e-6767-4686-9cd4-60788de11f47" (DocumentUploadWebPart).
>   Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/6d68696e-6767-4686-9cd4-60788de11f47_0.0.1 external__react_.createClass is not a function
>   ***CALLSTACK:
>   SPError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:8671:24
>   SPLoaderError@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:4127:21
>   **WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT**https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3786:21
>   **WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT**https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3694:16
>   _loadComponentImpl/<@https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:6939:15

DocumentUpload.tsx

```
var App = React.createClass({ getInitialState() {
return { text: 'Enter Rich Text Description' }; },

render() {
var divStyle = {
  background: "#eee",
  padding: "10px",
  margin: "1px",
  width: "100%",
  height: "140px",
};

return (
  <div style={divStyle}>
    <Editor
      text={this.state.text}
      onChange={this.props.handleChange}
    />
  </div>
); },handleChange(text, medium) { this.setState({ text: text }); } });
```

IDocumentUploadProps.ts

```
import { SPHttpClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
export interface IDocumentUploadProps {
  spHttpClient: SPHttpClient;
  description: string;
  ProjectName: string;
  ProjectsArray: Array<string>[];
  siteurl: string;
  Building: string;
  Floor: string;
  GridLine: string;
  Subject: string;
  SubContractor: string;
  CreatedDate: string;
  RequiredDate: string;
  Disciplined: string;
  Description: string;
  Requirement: string;
  Comments: string;
  ItemGuid:string;
  loading: boolean;
  UploadedFilesArray: Array<string>[];
  CurrentUser: string;
  UserGroup: string;
  IRFINumber: string;
  IRFISeriesId: string;
  IRFIReference: string; }
```

SPFX version: 1.7.1
node version: 8.15.0
npm version: 6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The error states `external__react_.createClass is not a function`. This is because [React.createClass has been removed as of React v16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html) (which is used by SPFx v1.7.1). [Here is an official blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass) which explains how to migrate older code, using `create-react-class` as a drop-in replacement.

Alternatively, in my experience, SPFx works fine with the ES6 class notation, e.g.: `class App extends React.Component { /* ... */ }`. You can refactor your code to use the more modern ES6 notation. However, you would need to refactor out some other things as well such as `getInitialState`, so that might not be immediately feasible.